# Reference for Lovász Theta being a lower bound on the fractional chromatic number

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, coloring

I have recently had a chance to think about the various known lower bounds on the graph chromatic number, and how they relate to each other. Having found no single place where these relations appear, I have updated the "Graph coloring" Wikipedia page with this info.

I would like to add a reference for the fact that Lovász's Theta for the complementary graph is a lower bound on the fractional coloring number. This is fairly obvious by construction, but maybe not immediately obvious, and I feel that giving a proof within the Wikipedia article is somewhat inappropriate.